# error: cannot find symbol method

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a fileReader method, but every time I go to compile, I get the error:

error: cannot find symbol

-->   fileReader list = new fileReader();

I've checked through numerous posts on multiple sites but I can't figure this one out.

```
public ArrayList<String> fileReader()
{
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));)
    {
        while (s.hasNext())
            list.add(s.next());
        s.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    }
  return(list);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a key: ");
int key = user.nextInt();
fileReader list = new fileReader();
```

Comment: Use `FileReader` instead of `fileReader`.

Comment: fileReader() is a method or a constructor? Seems it's a method and you should remove the "new" keyword.

Comment: It was a method, you are correct and that fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate a method. `fileReader` is a method and not a class hence this statement is not valid:

fileReader
Multiple problems here:

1. The `fileReader` is a method so cannot instantiate it using `new`. 
   Remove the new keyword.
2. `fileReader` is not a static method so you cannot call it directly in your main method. 
   To solve this problem either mark `fileReader` method as static or create the instance of your class and then call `fileReader` on that instance.
3. Finally you need to create an instance of List to use the returned list from fileReader method. So change it to something like:

   List list = fileReader(); // if fileReader is marked as static

   List list = new yourClass().fileReader(); // if fileReader is a non-static method

Comment: I get it now, it's been a while since I've done Java but I remember having this problem before, of course I forgot the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
List<String> list = fileReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

`new` keyword is used to create instances of classes not for calling methods.
`fileReader()` is a method not a class,So it either using `instance` of your class or `make it static` and call it directly.
I changed `fileReader()` to static method like this

```
public static ArrayList<String> fileReader()
{
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));)
    {
        while (s.hasNext())
            list.add(s.next());
        s.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    }
  return(list);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter a key: ");
   int key = user.nextInt();
   fileReader list = fileReader();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate a method. fileReader is a method and not a class hence this statement is not valid:

1、If you want to call the main method fileReader method, you can add the static keyword to fileReader

```
 //add static
public static ArrayList<String> fileReader() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        //removed brackets 
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
        while (s.hasNext())
            list.add(s.next());
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    }
    return (list);
}
```